# Why use one vs the other: `boost::shared_array` VS `boost::shared_ptr<std::vector>`?

Tags: c++, boost, stl, shared-ptr, raii

So to deal with large blobs of memory either for an image or similar there are clearly lots of options.

Since I'm a fan of smart pointers and RAII I'm wondering about whether it's smarter to go with :

- a `shared_ptr` to a `std::vector`

or

- to go with a `shared_array` pointing to a dynamically allocated array.

What are the conceptual, practical, and performance implications of choosing one vs the other?

Comment: and what's wrong with simply `std::vector`? when shared_* is used it usually means there is no owner, which is frequently a desing defect.

Comment: I need to be able to transfer ownership.

Comment: @Gene Bushuyev: I disagree. At least when I use `shared_ptr` and friends (or other smart pointer implementations), they are used only when there are multiple simultaneous owners with lifetimes that cannot be determined during compile time. Granted they don't occur often, but they have a legitimate use.

Comment: @Catskul: the way to transfer ownership of a `vector` is `swap()`. You should only need `shared_ptr<vector<T> >` when you're actually using the refcounting, that is when multiple different owners need to access the same vector, and you don't know which one will need it longest.

Comment: @In silico - I didn't say they have no legitimate use, I simply said it's infrequent. In practice I noticed they were often used either due to a defective design (where ownership issues were not correctly addressed), or as a poor substitute for `unique_ptr`.

Comment: @Gene Bushuyev: In that case, I totally agree. :-)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's the same as comparing std::vector vs. C array.

Think about `shared_array` as a RAII C array. What you get is just automatic memory deallocation. Useful in cases when you deal with 3rd-party code that returns arrays. 
Theoretically it's faster than std::vector in some edge cases, but much less flexible and less  secure.

std::vector is probably the better choice.

Comment: Can you think of any particular reason an array would be any faster than std::vector?

Comment: I can imagine arrays being *marginally* faster when you know the number of elements in advance, because `new[]` *may* not overallocate (at least, not as much as `std::vector`). Again, the speed benefits are usually marginal.

Comment: `std::vector` simply wraps an ordinary array, so at least accesses should be as fast as raw arrays when the compiler optimizes the code.

Comment: @Larsmans: completely agreed. @Catskul: to enumerate some other rather farfetched cases: optimization turned off, not inlined vector methods invocation (bad compiler?), improper usage of iterators, overuse of `std::vector::erase()` etc. It's why I said "***theoretically*** it's faster"

Answer (score 3):

`shared_ptr` to `std::vector`

- `+` allows amortized constant time `push_back`
- `-` introduces an extra level of indirection over `std::vector`

`shared_array`

- `+` does not introduce an extra level of indirection
- `-` does not allow amortized constant time append, unless you implement it yourself, which again would take an extra level of indirection.

Comment: re: `shared_ptr to std::vector` Won't the extra level of indirection be likely optimized away in most cases as far as performance is concerned?

Comment: @Catskul: an extra level of indirection *can't* be optimized away in nearly any practical situation. Whether the performance hit is significant is another question entirely. I'd say use `shared_array` when possible, because it's simple, and `shared_ptr` to `vector` when you need to change the length of the array.

Comment: @larsman either might look like `(*imageData)[index]`. In each case a dereference of imageData happens and then a second dereference happens after the pointer arithmetic for the subscript operator in either case. It seems like they would be equivalent, but also optimizable at least in the case of the first dereference, no?

Comment: @Catskul: `shared_array<T>` wraps a pointer to `T`; `vector<T>` wraps a pointer to `T`; `shared_ptr<vector<T> >` wraps a pointer to a pointer to `T`. With `shared_array<T> a`, you'd get the `i`'th element with `a[i]`; with the `shared_ptr` solution, you'd get the same with `(*a)[i]`.

Comment: @Catskul: If you were a compiler, how would you optimise out a pointer dereference?

Comment: @Tomalak if there were many in a row and I could prove that the underlying pointer would not change in the mean time, do all the operations in a register and write it back after.  consider "int foo = 0; int * bar = &foo; int ** borf = &bar; for(int i=0;i<10;++i) ++(**borf);"

Comment: @Catskul: and you're also going to do that optimization for a templated class used across multiple translation units?

Comment: I bench-marked and it turns out that the std::vector was faster than a dynamically allocated array, but probably only because of page_faults. And the shared_ptr and shared_array wrappers made no performance difference for access.