# Usage of std::shared_ptr

Tags: c++, shared-ptr

How can I use std::shared_ptr for array of double? Additionally what are advantages/disadvantages of using shared_ptr.

Comment: You don't use `std::shared_ptr` for a dynamically allocated array, it doesn't call the proper `delete`. You probably want `std::vector<double>`.

Comment: @birryree: Technically speaking, you could go for a std::shared_ptr<std::vector<double>> if the shared ownership semantics were important to you. Or Boost's shared_array. See this question for example: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6796655/why-use-one-vs-the-other-boostshared-array-vs-boostshared-ptrstdvecto

Comment: @StuartGolodetz - good point about the ownership semantics. piyush314 would have to know that `shared_array` is a Boost construct (not standard), and if he really, really wanted a raw allocated array, he could use a `std::default_delete<T[]>` argument for the pointer deleter, like this: `std::shared_ptr<double> name(new double[size], std::default_delete<double[]>());`.

Comment: Indeed - I was just adding 'Boost's' there while you were writing that :)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

It depends on what you're after. If you just want a resizable array of doubles, go with

```
std::vector<double>
```

Example:

```
std::vector<double> v;
v.push_back(23.0);
std::cout << v[0];
```

If sharing the ownership of said array matters to you, use e.g.

```
std::shared_ptr<std::vector<double>>
```

Example:

```
std::shared_ptr<std::vector<double>> v1(new std::vector<double>);
v1->push_back(23.0);
std::shared_ptr<std::vector<double>> v2 = v1;
v2->push_back(9.0);
std::cout << (*v1)[1];
```

Alternatively, Boost has

```
boost::shared_array
```

which serves a similar purpose. See here:

http://www.boost.org/libs/smart_ptr/shared_array.htm

As far as a few advantages/disadvantages of shared_ptr go:

Pros

- Automated shared resource deallocation based on reference counting - helps avoid memory leaks and other problems associated with things not getting deallocated when they should be
- Can make it easier to write exception-safe code

Cons

- Memory overhead to store the reference count can be significant for small objects
- Performance can be worse than for raw pointers (but measure this)

Answer (score 5):

You can also provide an [array deleter:](http://anteru.net/2008/09/01/260/)

```
template class ArrayDeleter {
public:
    void operator () (T* d) const
    { delete [] d; }
};

int main ()
{
    std::shared_ptr array (new double [256], ArrayDeleter ());
}
```

Comment: You could also just use a lambda, I think: `std::shared_ptr<double> array(new double[256], [](double *d) { delete [] d; } );`.