# should I continue to use boost::shared_array or use boost::shared_ptr<type []> instead?

Tags: c++, boost

> Starting with Boost release 1.53, shared_ptr can be used to hold a
>   pointer to a dynamically allocated array.
>   (http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_55_0/libs/smart_ptr/shared_ptr.htm)

Also, using shared_ptr has the benefit of allocator functions like boost::make_shared< int [] >(...);
Should I start using boost::shared_ptr instead of boost::shared_array when possible? it seems boost::shared_ptr can do most of the work boost::shared_array does.

Comment: One advantage of `shared_array` is that it overrides the `[]` operator. With `shared_ptr<T[]>` you'd need to dereference the pointer first: `(*sharedPtr)[i]` rather than `sharedArray[i]`

Comment: `std::vector` is often a better choice.

Comment: @Nick: No need for that, `shared_ptr` has support for `operator[]` for array types, which on the other hand hasn't support for `operator->` or `operator*`. See http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_55_0/boost/smart_ptr/shared_ptr.hpp

Comment: Things have moved on since I was last using Boost!

Comment: @MaximYegorushkin: Thanks. maybe shared_ptr<std::vector> will solve most of the problems.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the code is correct and working, I would not do the subject change.

If I had spare time and desire to do the change nevertheless, I would migrate to `std::shared_ptr<T[]>` straight away.

Answer (score 0):

Yes and one important benefit of using shared_ptr is that you no longer need to release the memory explicitly. The shared_ptr is a smart pointer and hence deallocates the memory by himself hence avoiding any memory leak. Also there is similar question exist on SO please visit the link [Why use one vs the other: `boost::shared_array` VS `boost::shared_ptr<std::vector>`?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6796655/why-use-one-vs-the-other-boostshared-array-vs-boostshared-ptrstdvecto)

Comment: `shared_array`, which author is using already **is too** a smart pointer